# Synchronizing apple id and google play store

Tags: apple-id

Can you link/sync apple id and google play store account? So for example, you can buy in-app purchases stuff in a google play store account then use it in the apple account?

Answer (score 1):

Unless this feature is implemented manually by the specific developer of the app in question, no.